# Inheritance from expanded decltype in variadic template

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, variadic-templates

I was experimenting with C++ template metaprogramming trying to create a storage class with the following semantics: it takes arbitrary number of types and stores a container of user-defined type for each of them with common access interface. I was able to implement it with following code using multiple inheritance from decltype-expanded list  (`A` and `B` are just dummy structures to be put into `Storage`):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

struct A
{
  int v = -1;
};

struct B
{
  std::string v;
};

typedef int Key;

template<typename T>
auto componentContainer();

template<>
auto componentContainer<A>()
{
    return std::unordered_map<Key, A>();
}

template<>
auto componentContainer<B>()
{
    return std::map<Key, B>();
}

template<typename... Component> 
struct Storage : public decltype(componentContainer<Component>())...
{
    template <typename T>
    using Container = decltype(componentContainer<T>());

    template<typename T>
    T& get(int index)
    {
       return Container<T>::operator [](index);
    }    

    template<typename T>
    const T& get(int index) const
    {
        return Container<T>::operator [](index);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void put(int index, const T& v)
    {
       Container<T>::operator [](index) = v;
    }    

    template<typename T, typename F>
    void apply(F f)
    {
        for (auto p = Container<T>::begin(); 
             p != Container<T>::end();
             p++)
        {
            f(p);
        }
    } 
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Storage<A,B> s;
    s.put<A>(0,  {12});
    s.put<A>(3,  {42});
    s.put<B>(0, {"melta"});
    s.put<B>(42, {"multimelta"});

    auto printer = [](auto p) { std::cout <<p->first <<": " << p->second.v <<std::endl;};
    s.apply<A>(printer);
    s.apply<B>(printer);

   return 0;
}
```

This code compiles just fine in gcc 5.1.0 and produces an expected result, but fails to compile in Visual Studio 2015 with following error message:

```
main.cpp(37): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '...'
main.cpp(70): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Storage<Component...>' being compiled
main.cpp(37): error C3520: 'Component': parameter pack must be expanded in this context
main.cpp(74): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Storage<A,B>' being compiled
main.cpp(37): error C3770: 'unknown-type': is not a valid base class
```

The thing is, I'm not sure if it's legal (i.e., standard-compliant) to inherit from expanded decltype list like that. So, my questions are:

1. Is `struct Storage: public decltype(componentContainer<Component>())...` a legal thing in standard C++ or is it a gcc feature?
2. If it is, can in be done in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me in MSVC.

```
template<typename T>
struct StorageBase
{
    using Type = decltype(componentContainer<T>());
};

template<typename... Component> 
struct Storage : public StorageBase<Component>::Type... 
{ }
```

The syntax error leads me to believe that the compiler is trying to evaluate the `decltype` expression before expanding the parameter pack - thus why it is also emitting `'Component': parameter pack must be expanded in this context`.

Simplifying the expression by using `StorageBase` to do the dirty work with `decltype` looks to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of inheritance, you might use composition (thanks to `std::tuple`):

```
template <typename T>
using Container = decltype(componentContainer<T>());

template <typename... Components> 
class Storage
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    T& get(int index) { return std::get<Container<T>>(t)[index]; }

    template<typename T>
    const T& get(int index) const { return std::get<Container<T>>(t).at(index); }

    template<typename T>
    void put(int index, const T& v) { std::get<Container<T>>(t)[index] = v; }

    template<typename T, typename F>
    void apply(F f)
    {
        for (const auto& p : std::get<Container<T>>(t))
        {
            f(p);
        }
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Container<Components>...> t;
};
```

Comment: This works! On a minor note, since std::tuple might be implemented recursively through inheritance (IIRC, it is in MSVS), it's may be actually be still through inheritance, though)